# Is there a way to align text in List View android

Tags: android

I'm creating a football points table in android app and unable to align text. Is there a way to align it perfectly. I'm fetching the data from MySQL on my server.

Here is the code for JSON parsing :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                if(success == 1){
                    JSONArray under8_club_league = jsonObject.getJSONArray("under8_club_league");
                    for(int i=0; i < under8_club_league.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject under8_club_league_object = under8_club_league.getJSONObject(i);
                        String team_name = under8_club_league_object.getString("team_name");
                        int played = under8_club_league_object.getInt("played");
                        int won = under8_club_league_object.getInt("won");
                        int lost = under8_club_league_object.getInt("lost");
                        int draw = under8_club_league_object.getInt("draw");
                        String GD = under8_club_league_object.getString("gd");
                        int points = under8_club_league_object.getInt("points");

                        String line = team_name + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + played + "  " + won + "  " + lost + "  " + "  " + draw + "  " + GD + "  " + points;

                        adapter.add(line);
```

Here is the output that I'm getting : [image]

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a RecyclerView and specify a layout file for each entry that has all the TextViews you need, spaced how you want them to be. Spaces aren't going to be consistent across devices.

Comment: If you don't want to use recyclerview and you have limited number of data, then go for Constraint layout ... But RecyclerView is definitely the best option. Although, constraint layout has less coding.

Comment: Do you want to say that alignment is not possible in ListView?

Comment: @UmangBurman yup, i have to feed the data for only 12 teams so data is limited and I didn't get you, constraint layout as in where? I've used constraint layout in my activity XML file.

Comment: Align what? Any description, any layouts? maybe there is images what is wrong and what is expected result?

Comment: Do you want me to give you the code for exact assignment of constraint layout for 12 teams.? I'll give you example, you need to replace them with your real data ok?

Comment: @UmangBurman Just give me an overview, I'll try to implement it .

Comment: @GensaGames Align team names and their stats according to the labels that I have given above.

Comment: Use constraint layout to match the positions of the given labels above and give wrap content.

Comment: @UmangBurman can you give me an example?

Comment: Prashant, I'll make the thing and post as an answer for you. OK

Comment: @UmangBurman Okay, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using text and trying to space it out you could do a cheaty method and use a monospace font (Please don't actually do this).

I'd recommend using a TableView and TableRow objects and then put each piece of text in its own TextView and add those textViews to each TableRow - the TableView will align the columns of each row.